# Authenticate an IOS device through a web app (using simple MDM api or not...)

Tags: php, ios, laravel, authentication, device

Hi i'm a junior developer . And i know very few in authentification with ios device.

Im working for a client who has a web app for his technician . They connect to the application with ipad through Safari.

The client wish to authenticate only the technician who use the web application with the ipad of the company.

Is there a way in PHP (the app is on Laravel) or javascript to retrieve the ipas or any ios device identification number like the UUID or something like that, to authenticate only those ipad ?

The Ipad are managed in a group with Simple MDM....
Is there a way with the API to authenticate the ipad??

Thank you very much and sorry for my poor english..

Comment: `The client wish to authenticate only the technician who use the web application with the ipad of the company`...you mean only one person should be allowed to use the web app from that device? Doesn't make a lot of sense really, as a requirement. What's the reason behind that? It shouldn't really matter where people are logging in from. If other people shouldn't be using the iPad, that not the web app's problem.

Comment: `Is there a way in PHP (the app is on Laravel) or javascript to retrieve the ipas or any ios device identification number like the UUID or something like that`...short answer, no. In a HTTP application you can really only get the IP address and the user agent. You don't know anything about the client device or software. And even then, IP addresses change, public IPs can be shared by hundreds of devices, and user agents are easy to spoof.

Comment: Or are you asking if it's possible for iOS to use the web application's authentication system to protect access to the whole ipad? Unlikely. MDM is more complex than that.

Comment: You could put the web application behind a firewall and configure a VPN profile via the MDM to provide access to it.  If the web app is accessible via the public internet then your only protection is username/password (plus any MFA that you configure) or you could distribute client SSL certificates to the devices via the MDM and have your web service require a valid client certificate

Comment: the technicians can exchange the ipads between them. I dont really know why the client wants to do that. I think its to be sure he can "see" what his tech are doing or where they are with the simpleMDM app maybe?

Comment: @Paulw11  thank you for your fast answer. I will look further in the direction you propose.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for these precisionsI will continue to search :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are planning to achieve, there is a simple way to do that. You could store a unique token in the cookies for each device. Then before you display the web app content, validate whether that device with the unique token cookies is allowed to access the web app.

So, when the iPad accesses the web app for the first time, the web app will generate a random number (token) and store it in both the client cookies and the web app DB. Then, the admin will allow this device to access the web app. Therefore, on next access from the same device the permission will be granted.

The issue from this approach is when the cookie is stolen and replicated on another device to grant access. Thus, it is important to enable other security practices (i.e. SSL, web application firewall, physical security of the iPad, etc.) to reduce the risk. But it is hard to eliminate it.

The other approach is through client certificates. I did not try this approach but it should work. You need to install a [client certificate on the iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html) and require client certificate authentication from the web service and access the web app through safari. It should use the pre-installed client certificate to authenticate the request.